# Provide security standards for ms access database

Tags: database, ms-access

Since I am going to ask simple question any help will be appreciated.
I went through SQL tutorial almost everything including (DDL, DML), however, now I have to design a library management application and found that I need to include security such as Administrator, Employee.
I searched the Internet and found that (DCL) is the way to do that 
My question :)
1) since I am using ms access, is (DCL) option in it?if not how to apply security in ms access

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear as to what exactly you're trying to do.

If you have an Access DB with a connection to a SQL Server, you can run DCL commands via   VBA SQL calls (**not** from the query window) to apply user control to the SQL Server.

However if you're asking about user control for an MS Access front-end, DCL does not apply, and furthermore, your options are very limited (if any serious level of security is required).

Friends and I use to race to see who could "hack" past MS Office security the fastest... as in, one to two minutes.  Nowadays, Microsoft doesn't bother including the features.

> You could try using the older `.MDB` file format, and applying Access User Level Security, as outlined in the [Access Security FAQ](https://support.microsoft.com/help/207793/microsoft-access-security-faq-available-in-the-download-center): ULS was removed from the newer `.ACCDB` file format.
>
> Recognize, though, that Access security definitely isn't unbreakable. If there's a need for strong security, you'd probably be better off putting your backend database into SQL Server.
>   <sup>([**Source**](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-access/user-level-password-protection-in-access-2010/24b2e3ae-75e0-4f8d-b4a7-1b58349b9b05?db=5))</sup>

If you want to learn about Access, I'd suggest you do a couple Access tutorials (not SQL).  The two are related but far from interchangeable, kind of like how VB and VBA are related but not interchangeable.

Comment: well,thank you for the answer, to be more clear i am using "Microsoft Access for desktop " not "Microsoft SQL Server" and i am a newbie.
i just found that "Microsoft SQL Server" support security but i couldn't find anything for "Microsoft Access for desktop "

Comment: @MostafaAbbas - Microsoft SQL Server is not the same as Microsoft Access -- they can communicate with each other, but that's it.  When you need to search for answers related to Access, I would suggest specifying `"MS Access"` or `"Microsoft Access"` (**with** the "quotes", since *access* is a very common, vague word in computer-related sites).

Comment: @MostafaAbbas - Note that you have a lot to learn & build before you'll need to worry about User Management; don't get ahead of yourself.  plan your table layout and get the DB working before concern about users.  Here's a decent basic tutorial specific to Access: [**QuackIt: Microsoft Access Tutorial**](https://www.quackit.com/microsoft_access/tutorial/). Here's [Microsoft's **Database Design Basics**](https://support.office.com/article/database-design-basics-eb2159cf-1e30-401a-8084-bd4f9c9ca1f5) and a video on [**Database Planning**](https://youtu.be/i72fVNqfWL4).

Comment: i am thankful to you for the information , a little advice will be really useful , if i finished my database creation the security will only be apply to the ** front-end ** ?

Answer (score 1):

No, DCL is not an option in MS Access.

When you are researching things like this, keep in mind that a lot of generic database concepts have limited application in MS Access because MS Access does not provide many features of advanced database management systems.

If you have chosen MS Access as your platform, try to read only MS Access based sources of information, not generic database information. Otherwise you'll get confused.

Here are some examples of implementing security in MS Access

I know link based answers are not an answer but this may help

- Using windows login, so no extra login is required

http://www.blueclaw-db.com/download/access_security_alternative.htm

- Native MS Access security - do *not* use this, it's too complicated and probably not supported any more

https://www.thoughtco.com/microsoft-access-user-level-security-tutorial-1019981

- Some other suggestions:

[How to implement user-level security in Access 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24891363/how-to-implement-user-level-security-in-access-2007)

Comment: thank you , it was really really confusing before,  you guys answered me in sufficient manner .